# laravel request validation using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

i'm trying to make validation in laravel but the code isn't returning in ajax here is my controller function :

```
public function postIndex(CategoryRequest $request ){

    $request->store();

    return ['status' => 'success' ,'data' => 'Data has been added successfully'];
}
```

and that's my request :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class CategoryRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name_ar' => 'required',
            'name_en' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation messages
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name_ar.required' => 'Please enter the name in arabic',
            'name_en.required' => 'Please enter the name in english'
        ];
    }


    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {

        if ($validator->fails()){
            return ['status' => 'error' ,'data' => $validator->messages()->getMessages()];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Store data function
     *
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $category = new Category();

        if ($category->save()){
            $category->details()->create([
                'name' => $this->name_en,
                'lang' => 'en'
            ]);
            $category->details()->create([
                'name' => $this->name_ar,
                'lang' => 'ar'
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     *Edit data function
     */
    public function edit($id){
        $category = Category::find($id);

        $category->english()->update([
            'name' => $this->name_en
        ]);
        $category->arabic()->update([
            'name' => $this->name_ar
        ]);
    }
}
```

i need to get the error messages using ajax but i don't know how to make it from request , i already can do it from the controller but i want my code to be clear so how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey guys i found out the error , i had to add these two function in request file :

```
protected function formatErrors(Validator $validator)
{
    $result = ['status' => 'error' ,'data' => implode(PHP_EOL ,$validator->errors()->all())];

    return $result;
}

public function response (array $errors) {
    return response()->json($errors, 200);
}
```

after i added them , the errors are now shown in ajax

Comment: Thank you for setting me in the right direction. Helped me to find this comment with the latest options.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-make-a-custom-formrequest-error-response-in-laravel-55?reply=427724